# GoogleMock and QString argument

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to use gmock with custom string type.

I have a method with `QString` argument which I want to mock:

`MOCK_METHOD1(getValue, int(QString key))`;

I set an expectation:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock, getValue("someKey"));
```

Got an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'MyMock::gmock_getValue(const char[8])'

include/gmock/gmock.h:9339:20: note: in definition of macro 'GMOCK_EXPECT_CALL_IMPL_'
     ((obj).gmock_##call).InternalExpectedAt(__FILE__, __LINE__, #obj, #call)
 note: in expansion of macro 'EXPECT_CALL'

...

gmock/gmock.h:9730:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from 'const char [6]' to 'const testing::Matcher<const QString&>&'
       gmock_##Method(GMOCK_MATCHER_(tn, F, 1) gmock_a1, \
```

But this works:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock, getValue(QString("someKey")));
```

How can I use string arguments without wrapping each string literal with `QString()` ?

Comment: why don't you want to wrap each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to `"someKey"` is not a QString, it is a `const char[8]` as reported by the error and Google Test / Mock requires that the 2 classes are the same.

In the same way a compiler does not know if the value 10 is supposed to be int32 int64, uint32 or uint64, the same applies.

Comment: maybe i could create custom matcher for QString?

Comment: Not sure, I do not have experience with gmock and those matchers

Comment: The point is that `QString` is not implicitly convertible from `const char*`. You could write a custom matcher, but your code wouldn't look better: `EXPECT_CALL(mock, getValue(Matcher("someKey")));`